# Want to create folders and put images on it reading it's path from a .txt with a script

Tags: batch-file

First of all, this will be the first time I ask for a question, since I couldn't find the answer. Sorry if it was already posted(or something similar) and I couldn't see it or if the style of it it's not correct.

**Summary:** I never tried Batch before but I need it to simplify my life in order to move some images. I have tried some bash before so I though it could be similar, with what I found I got:

```
ECHO OFF 
REM extension should be .bat 
FOR /L %%x IN (0,1,23) DO mkdir C:\Users\UB\Documents\%%x

REM so now folders should be created, each with the name X, X from 0 to 23 

REM want to put images on the folders 
REM images are on the patch Documents\Data\Images\Y. 
REM Being Y something like that : 12/2016/04/20/112844.jpg 
I had a .txt with a list of the images path Y space Z, 
where Z is the number of the folder I want them to be, 
as an example: 12/2016/04/20/112844.jpg 17


ECHO "done"
```

**What I want:** the idea is to create 23 folders with name from 0 to 23.
After that I would want to read the .txt and move each image to the folder it corresponds according to the .txt file.
As you see I didn't get to much so any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** SO now I can create the folders and the only help will be reading the .txt and coping the images to the new folders.

Also, as a few extra questions:

1. is the way of the comments right? :: coment:: -SOLVED-
2. is ECHO really a print? -SOLVED-

**UPDATE 2:** I run the code below which an user provided trying to adapt it but get an error at running it saying the syntax is or the name provided is wrong.

```
mkdir C:\Users\UB\Documents\Activities
FOR /L %%x IN (0,1,23) DO mkdir C:\Users\UB\Documents\Activities\%%x
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%I in ("annotations.txt") do move /C:\Users\UB\Documents\dades\images\%%I C:\Users\UB\Documents\Activities\%%J
```

**May it be:** I have a problem since in .txt there is  `10/2016/06/01/132316.jpg 17` as well as `10/2016/06/01/132216.jpg 8` ? like one have for destination a one digit folder and one a two digit one

my .txt is as such:

```
10/2016/06/01/132316.jpg 17
10/2016/06/01/132348.jpg 19
10/2016/06/01/132420.jpg 11
10/2016/06/01/132452.jpg 19
10/2016/06/01/132524.jpg 17
10/2016/06/01/132556.jpg 17
10/2016/06/01/132628.jpg 17
```

with almost 1000 rows like this

Comment: Take a look at [`rem`](https://ss64.com/nt/rem.html) and [`echo`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) as well as [`for /L`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)...

Comment: Tp parse yoour `.txt` file also read [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: @aschipfl i read it and i think that the first step, making the directories is good now. any idea about the second step, reading and passing the imatges to that folders?

Comment: thanks! i get it to work now